# Emacs matching tags highlighting

Tags: xml, emacs, tags, highlighting, matching

When Paren Match Highlighting (in the Options menu) is enabled, it nicely highlights matched parentheses. Is there something like this but for XML tags? For example, if I had:

```
<para> lksjdflksdjfksdjf </para>
```

it would highlight both tags if my point was anywhere inside one of the tags (even including the less-than and greater-than signs).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mike Spindel has written a minor mode, [hl-tags-mode](https://github.com/deactivated/hl-tags-mode), which provides this feature.

Comment: One more question. Any idea how to switch the color of highlighting? Say from the current pink to yellow? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, try this: (set-face-background 'show-paren-match-face "Yellow")