# How to enable html tag pair highlighting mode in Ergoemacs

Tags: html, bash, emacs, html-editor, ergoemacs

How to enable HTML tag pair highlighting mode in Ergoemacs.

I'm using the Ergo- version of Emacs on Windows 7 -- i.e., Ergoemacs.

I found a thread that deals with a similar issue -- i.e., `sgml` and `xml` tags:  [Emacs matching tags highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784334/emacs-matching-tags-highlighting)

The suggested solution in that other thread was to use a library called `hl-tags-mode.el`, which is located at the following Github link:

https://github.com/deactivated/hl-tags-mode/blob/master/hl-tags-mode.el

I copied that `hl-tags-mode.el` library to my `.emacs.d/` folder and pressed `Alt-a hg-tags-mode` -- Emacs gives me a message that states *"No Match"*.

---

In the end:
I let go of ergoemacs and the following steps worked:

1. Download emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip from the web
2. Unzip to d:\emacs-24.3\
3. Download hl-tags-mode.el to D:\emacs-24.3\site-lisp\
4. Add

`(require 'hl-tags-mode)
    (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook (lambda () (hl-tags-mode 1)))
    (add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook (lambda () (hl-tags-mode 1)))`

to C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming.emacs

Start up emacs and open an html file and voila!  matching tags
are highlighted

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on lines 26, 27 and 28 of the source code?  https://github.com/deactivated/hl-tags-mode/blob/master/hl-tags-mode.el  *To use hl-tags-mode, add the following to your .emacs*: `(require 'hl-tags-mode) (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook (lambda () (hl-tags-mode 1))) (add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook (lambda () (hl-tags-mode 1)))`  If you did that, how about trying a virtually blank `.emacs` file (with only the above settings) and only that one particular library to see whether it works without any other potential conflicts in your user-configuration (e.g., other libraries, etc.)

Comment: I assume you also read the part in the library (at lines 21 and 22) which states:  `hl-tags-mode is a minor mode for SGML and XML editing that
;; highlights the current start and end tag.`  Thus, you may need to do some modifications to that source code to be able to use it with `html`.

Comment: Please review my edits to your initial question -- hopefully, it now states more clearly your intended question, and it may help to reduce negative reputation points and/or votes to close your question because the issue is not clear.  If you feel that I have misinterpreted your question, please feel free to edit it again to your liking.

Comment: @user3521285 Just to make sure you are aware of it: StackOverflow allows you to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and even accept the answer after 48 hours). So you might want to consider moving the solution you added to your question to an actual answer.